# Msg 8152, Level 16, State 2, Line 1. Finding which columns will be truncated

Tags: sql, sql-server, truncate

I was delegated to maintain a table from an external DB with the data I handle on my DB, what I'm faced now it's getting data from my DB to that table, the problem being the length of the values I have (data it's 90% equivalent at worst, but I also handle more precise data) and getting the classic:

> Msg 8152, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
>   Los datos de cadena o binarios se truncarían.

I know I could check each column and comparing total length but we are talking about 130 columns and more than 6 joins on my procedure.

I did `SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF` and found about 10 columns conflicting with the table (data shows clearly truncated values), but I still need to compare 120 columns with about 4k rows.

With that being said is there a easier/less manual way to detect which columns are raising errors?

Comment: Well, if you don't feel like comparing lengths yourself, you can wait for SQL Server 2019 and [it will tell you](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/what-s-new-in-sql-server-ver15?view=sqlallproducts-allversions#error-messages).

Comment: I ended up doing it manually, but that feature will surely help me the next time, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why not compare the table schema from each database to determine where the differences are.The truncation is only happening because the destination table is not allowing the same size data that the source table is allowing.